# Application crashes when trying to dispose an image

Tags: arrays, image, crash, dispose, picturebox

I'm creating an app with two pictureBoxes, where images load from a array and randomly change on every timer tick. I'm facing a problem of sometimes not loading the image, leaving the pictureBox with a little red cross. I read I should dispose the previous image before loading the new one (I'm a C# newbie), but I can't get it working without crashing the app on the first tick. Would you please help me out?

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index1 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length - 1);
        index2 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length - 1);
        pcb1.ImageLocation = pics[index1];
        pcb2.ImageLocation = pics[index2];
    }



try
{
    pcb1.Image.Dispose();
    pcb2.Image.Dispose();
    index1 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length - 1);
    index2 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length - 1);
    pcb1.ImageLocation = pics[index1];
    pcb2.ImageLocation = pics[index2];
}
catch (Exception)
{ 
    throw; 
}
```

- tells me System.ArgumentException

Comment: What exception is thrown?  Wrap that in try/catch if you haven't already and tell us what it reports.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Edited, hope that's what you meant. I'm a serious newbie.

Comment: ImageLocation...does pics[] contain a list of paths then?

Comment: Change:  index1 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length - 1);   To:  index1 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length);  (the 2nd parameter is _exclusive_).  Not sure Dispose() is required here because you're simply reassigning a value, not getting rid of the image object altogether.

Comment: @DonBoitnott string[] pics = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\pics\lvl1");  removing the -1 didn't help. I don't know how else to explain that some images don't load (I checked and every image from the folder shows up, just not always).

Comment: Is "rand" a member of type Rand?  You could just do:  Int32 I = new Random().Next(0, pics.Length);  I just set up a test and it works without error.  Regardless, if you're seeding your random perhaps the index is off.

Comment: There's nothing but valid images to be found at:  Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\pics\lvl1"?  What about it perhaps catching a system "Thumbs.db" file?  Try putting Image img = Image.FromFile(pics[index1]);  Then assigning "img" to the pictureBox.  FromFile() _will_ throw an exception if it's not a valid type, so the try/catch is essential in this block of code.

Comment: Added a possible solution for you...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
try
{
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index1 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length);
        if (File.Exists(pics[index1]))
        {
            Image img1 = Image.FromFile(pics[index1]);
            pcb1.Image = img1;
        }
        index2 = rand.Next(0, pics.Length);
        if (File.Exists(pics[index2]))
        {
            Image img2 = Image.FromFile(pics[index2]);
            pcb2.Image = img2;
        }
    }
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException oomEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid image.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //all others...respond appropriately
}
```

Comment: Yes, that indeed stopped the crashes and faulty loads, but now the refresh rate is very inconsistent. What could we do with that? By the way, thanks for all the help, it's appreciated. :)

Comment: That would be the file load time.  What's your Interval?  How many files/images do you anticipate finding?  You could slow it down.  If the image count is low enough, you could preload the images into a List<Image> or event a List<Byte[]>.  But you have to be careful, because the image in memory is volatile, and you could end up with more reference errors.